# npm Prefix path is not creating symlinks correctly in /usr/bin/

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, amazon-ec2, npm-install

I am using **(ec2 instance Linux)**  trying to install a cloud using **npm** which requires the symlinks to be created inside *"/usr/bin/"*  , but the problem **npm** is creating them in *"/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.10.0/bin/"*  I tried to change the prefix using this command "npm config set prefix /usr" but it still don't create the symlinks in the needed path and even it gives me that the ec2 is not compatible with the npm prefix path and I must delete it .

any solution ? need help I am stuck

Comment: can you try `ln -s /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.10.0/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm`

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan I tried , it even don't work

Comment: If you're using `nvm` it's going to do this.  Don't use `nvm` if you want to control where Node and its tools are installed.

Comment: @Joe so I must delete the node and install it again without the nvm ?